# Django queries on properties of related object sets

Tags: python, django

Say I have the following models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Teacher(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField()


class Student(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField()

    absent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    teacher = models.ForeignKey('Teacher',related_name='students')
```

If I wanted to look up a list of teachers who have *at least* one absent student, I can do the following:

```
Teacher.objects.filter(students__absent=True)
```

My question is, how would I come up with a list of teachers who, have *all* of their students absent, excluding the teachers who have no students at all? Is this even possible through the ORM without dropping into SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Teacher.objects.exclude(Q(students__absent=False) | Q(students=None))
```

This will exclude all teachers who have at least one non-absent student, or have no students at all.

Comment: No, this will exclude all teachers who have at least one non-absent student **and** have no students at all.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to approach it from the inverse. Thanks.

And seeing the comment above, i think you're looking for Teacher.objects.exclude(Q(students__absent=False) | Q(students=None))

But I appreciate you showing me the right approach.